# Jenkins Test Email works fine but Error Sending Email After Build Run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

In my Jenkins email setup Test Email works fine but I get "Error Sending email to following valid recipients ..." when execute the build.
My organisation's email server doesn't  require SMTP or SSL authentication and test email with same setup work perfectly.  I have added trigger as "Always".

What can cause this issue ?  Please see attached screenshots of my configuration and error i face.

Email ext plugin xml:/var/jenkins_home# cat hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher.xml

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisherDescriptor plugin="email-ext@2.63">
  <defaultSuffix>@tatacommunications.com</defaultSuffix>
  <mailAccount>
    <smtpHost>HERE I PROVIDED IP ADD OF SMTP SERVER</smtpHost>
    <smtpPort>25</smtpPort>
    <smtpPassword>{AQAAABAAAAAQxb/EfaXX7pdoeZ3BYi0Hmi4x4hDDVHCKgPLur86v/Ic=}</smtpPassword>
    <useSsl>false</useSsl>
  </mailAccount>
  <addAccounts/>
  <charset>UTF-8</charset>
  <defaultContentType>text/plain</defaultContentType>
  <defaultSubject>$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS!</defaultSubject>
  <defaultBody>$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS:&#xd;
&#xd;
Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results.</defaultBody>
  <defaultPresendScript></defaultPresendScript>
  <defaultPostsendScript></defaultPostsendScript>
  <defaultClasspath/>
  <defaultTriggerIds>
    <string>hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.trigger.AlwaysTrigger</string>
  </defaultTriggerIds>
  <maxAttachmentSize>-1</maxAttachmentSize>
  <recipientList>ujjawal.khare@x.com,cc:pradeep@x.com,cc:shasheesh@x.com</recipientList>
  <defaultReplyTo></defaultReplyTo>
  <allowedDomains>@x.com</allowedDomains>
  <excludedCommitters></excludedCommitters>
  <overrideGlobalSettings>true</overrideGlobalSettings>
  <precedenceBulk>false</precedenceBulk>
  <debugMode>false</debugMode>
  <requireAdminForTemplateTesting>false</requireAdminForTemplateTesting>
  <enableWatching>false</enableWatching>
  <enableAllowUnregistered>true</enableAllowUnregistered>
```

1. Email Configuration[image: Email Configuration]
2. Successful Test Email[image: Successful Test Email]
3. Error Sending mail post build[image: Error Sending mail post build]

Comment: Just guessing, where the mail step is? If in the post-build actions, then, of course, the mail is being sent afterwards, after job is done.

Comment: Yes @xxxvodnikxxx As you can see in 3rd screenshot, mail is sent after build execution is finished. Its just that when i test with test mail emails sends successfully (screenshot no. 2) but if run build then it fails.

Comment: Hi @UjjawalKhare, have you figured out the issue? I ran into it just now.